# “lazy-initialize” In ChartJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, chart.js, chart.js2

I am using `Chart.js` `Version: 1.1.1` for Data presentation on my page.
I have 5 different types of graph which get initialize on load of the page all at once.
Now I want to use `lazy-initialize` in my page.
Is there any workaround for `chartJS`

Thank You!!!

Comment: You can use setTimeout to delay the drawing of charts, but lazy-initialize is a totally different concept.

Comment: Hi b0y Please check the link: https://www.amcharts.com/kbase/make-the-charts-lazy-initialize-only-when-they-scroll-into-view/ something like this I want to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Explaining the concept with a `H1` element.
Whenever the `H1` will appear into the viewport, invoke a function to render the chart.

You can calculate the offset of the element(Graph's Div) and then compare that with the scroll value like:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
   var hT = $('#scroll-to').offset().top,
       hH = $('#scroll-to').outerHeight(),
       wH = $(window).height(),
       wS = $(this).scrollTop();
   if (wS > (hT+hH-wH) && (hT > wS) && (wS+wH > hT+hH)){
      $('h1').addClass('view')
   } else {
      $('h1').removeClass('view')
   }
});
```

Into the example, i have shown the demo for adding style to the `H1`. Instead you have to render your graph here.

Example: [**Demo Link**](http://jsfiddle.net/n4pdx/636/)